# What's the safe way to dynamically allocate vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-allocation

After dynamically allocating struct, I thought it woudl be prudent to put 'delete' at the end.  But it gave me a runtime error.  Compiled ok, though.  So if I get rid of 'delete', it runs fine.  But I worry there could be a memory leak.  What would be the safe way to handle this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    vector<char*> vstr;
    vector<int> vint;

}VecStrInt;

int main()
{
    VecStrInt * mtx = new VecStrInt();

    mtx[0].vstr.push_back("Hello");
    mtx[0].vint.push_back(1);

    cout<<mtx[0].vint.at(0)<<endl;
    cout<<mtx[0].vstr.at(0)<<endl;

    //delete [] mtx;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you may avoid new completely, `std::vector<VecStrInt> mtx;` or `VecStrInt mtx;` is enough (depending of what you want).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call of `delete[]` is not the same as the call of `delete` (note the square brackets).

You pair calls of `delete` with calls of `new`, and calls of `delete[]` with calls of `new SomeType[someCount]`.

In your case, you allocated a single object, not an array. Your object happens to *represent* a vector, which is an array, but it does not matter to C++: you allocated it with a "single" `new`, so you cannot apply an "array" `delete[]` to it.

Hence, you need to `delete` it using the regular delete operator:

```
delete mtx;
```

Note: there is rarely a situation when you should allocate `std::vector<T>` dynamically. The object that represents `std::vector<T>` itself is very small; the data is stored elsewhere, and is allocated dynamically. So you might as well use

```
VecStrInt mtx;
```

and skip `delete` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate only a single object like this then you have to use operator `delete`

```
VecStrInt * mtx = new VecStrInt();
//...
delete mtx;
```

If you allocate an array of objects (even if the array contains only one element) you have to use operator `delete[]` like this

```
VecStrInt * mtx = new VecStrInt[1];
//...
delete [] mtx;
```

Also you could use a standard smart pointer as for example `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be safe, you should not use `new`/`delete` directly like this, because an exception may be thrown in the middle of your function and the `delete` clause will not be executed.

The C++ way of allocating and deallocating things is done through constructors/destructors and is called [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). Standard classes handle this for you through their constructor/destructor. You can use for example :

- standard containers like `std::vector<T>` for multiple elements, instead of `T* = new T[]`
- `std::string` for strings instead of `char*`
- smart pointers, introduced by the C++11 standard (only for more complex cases) : `std::unique_ptr<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<T>`/`std::weak_ptr<T>`

**Note :** in your case, `mtx` is only used inside the `main` function, so you don't need to allocate it on the heap, you can just write :

```
int main()
{
    VecStrInt mtx;

    mtx.vstr.push_back("Hello");
    mtx.vint.push_back(1);

    cout << mtx.vint.at(0) << endl;
    cout << mtx.vstr.at(0) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Likewise, you should use `std::string` instead of `char*` in `VecStrInt`, to avoid memory leakage of strings :

```
#include <string>

struct VecStrInt
{
    vector<string> vstr;
    vector<int> vint;
};
```